# Copying a same file multiple times

Tags: linux, time, latency

I have an audio file, and I am running a script to decode that audio file. Now I want to measure the latency of the system.
So, I am running a script with a `time` command.
like `$ time ./uber.sh`
In the script `uber.sh` the file path to the audio file has been mentioned.
Now I want to check, the latency when there will be the same audio file 100,1000 and 10000 times. Initially, I am thinking about actually copying the same audio file 100,1000,10000 times and run the script again to measure time.

Is there any other method, in which I should not copy the same audio file multiple times (like 100 to 10000 times) and measure the time. But it will run the script for a single file, multiple times.

Comment: You haven't made it clear why you need to physically copy (create a copy of) this file multiple times.

Comment: How do you measure the latency?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to create a loop in `bash` shell/terminal?

Example:

```
for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do date --iso=ns; echo $i; time sleep 0.1s; done
```

And if you feel like it, you can replace all semicolons with line feeds. And with `bash` the command line usage uses the same syntax as scripts so you can just put that in a text file and `chmod a+x myfilename` to turn it into executable script.